# React how to have a case-sensitive path when Route uses render?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I saw that Route now supports a `sensitive` prop to make sure the path is case-sensitive. I tried it with my implementation but it didn't work:

```
<Route
 sensitive
 path="/somePath"
 render={props => (
   <Page>
    <PageName {...props} />
   </Page>
 )}
/>
```

When I navigate to `somepath`, it still redirects me to `somePath`. Is there something different I need to do with the render function being used?

EDIT: I'm trying to make my URL case-sensitive. So navigating to `somepath` should fail; it shouldn't redirect me to `somePath`.

Comment: Have you tried simply using path.toLowerCase()? It seems to fix the problem you are encounter, but let me know if that does not work.

Comment: urls are *largely* case-insensitive... What use-case are you trying to do right now?

Comment: I'm trying to make my URL case-sensitive. So navigating to `somepath` should fail; it shouldn't redirect me to `somePath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `caseSensitive` prop](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/route#casesensitive), which instructs the route to match case:

```
<Route caseSensitive path="/wEll-aCtuA11y" />
```

The above example will match "wEll-aCtuA11y" but will not match "well-actua11y".